# PHP PDO fatal error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following query:

```
$sql  = "UPDATE db.users SET $str WHERE users.{$this->row} = {$this->value} LIMIT 1";
```

Which echo's out:

```
UPDATE db.users SET username=testUser, gid=3 WHERE users.username = mmiller LIMIT 1
```

However when I do:

```
$count = Db::init()->exec($sql);
```

I get:

> ```
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
> ```
>
> 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found:
>   1054 Unknown column 'mmiller' in
>   'where clause'' in
>   /class.php:185
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /class.php(185):
>   PDO->exec('UPDATE db...') #1
>   /class.php(194):
>   User->modify('username', 'gid',
>   'testUser', '3') #2 {main} thrown in
>   /class.php
>   on line 185

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `"`

```
UPDATE db.users SET username="testUser", gid="3" WHERE users.username = "mmiller" LIMIT 1
```

Make sure your echo shows you that. You could use `'` ofcourse, whatever floats your boat :)

Comment: probably for "testuser" this time? I'll fix that too :P

Comment: You have to add the `'` around the `{$this->value}`, but there is also a wrong assignment withing that `$set` variable. Also: you say you don't need prep. statements, but you wouldn't be having this problem if you did you use them....

Answer (score 2):

You need to use quotes around string values;

```
 $sql = "UPDATE db.users SET $str WHERE users.{$this->row} = '{$this->value}' LIMIT 1";
```

Seeing you're already using PDO, it might be beneficial to use prepared statements. Although a bit slower for a one-off query, it increases security and handles all escaping necessary, so you won't run in to these problems.

Comment: Theres no user input so Im not in need for prep statements. However putting this in quotes just returns the same error

Comment: @Headspin Somehow, your database thinks "mmiller" is a column, instead of a value. That usually boils down to having forgotten the quotes around a string value. If you put it in quotes, there's no way your database will think you're referring to a column.

Comment: You know what, yer right, its was just one of the values in the $str string that needed the quotes around it. Correct for more complete answer. Thanks